# Перенос сети на другой домен

Tags: wordpress

Есть сайт на Wordpress работающий в режиме мультисайт. Как перенести основной сайт сети на новый домен?

Comment: Физически файлы сайта перемещаются?

Comment: @SeVlad файлы сайта остаются на месте.

Answer (score 1):

Вариант1.

1. Скопировать базу в новую (сделать дамп, залить его в новую базу).
2. В отдельный каталог, ВНЕ основного, залить ВП скопировав конфиг, но изменив данные новой базы. (ВП нужен только для того чтобы заработал скрипт. Потом его удалить)
3. С пом. [скрипта](https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/) изменить домен. Быть оч. внимательным - учитывать `http://`, `www`, включение в емейлах (`@`), последний слеш, и возможно в названии каталога на хостинге.
4. Изменить в конфиге рабочего сайта данные коннекта к новой БД.

Вариант2. 
Использовать плагины для миграции.
Напр. платная версия [дубликатора](https://snapcreek.com/duplicator/), судя по описанию, это может.
Также наверняка есть и другие.